# @PreAuthorize not working - Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, user-roles

I'm trying an example on spring security (user-role authorization) using @PreAuthorize annotation, got stuck up with below error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:         
    Failed to instantiate [org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor]:    
    Factory method 'methodSecurityInterceptor' threw exception; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
                ... 91 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityInterceptor': Requested bean is currently in creation: I
        s there an unresolvable circular reference?
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:347)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
                at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor.getAdvice(MethodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor.java:107)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJProxyUtils.isAspectJAdvice(AspectJProxyUtils.java:67)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJProxyUtils.makeAdvisorChainAspectJCapableIfNecessary(AspectJProxyUtils.java:49)
```

My **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** extension class is:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends
        WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
                .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll()
                .and().httpBasic()

                .and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access?error");

}
```

And method level authorization check in UserController:

```
 @Controller
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class UserController {
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('111')")
        @RequestMapping(value = "/users")
        public String userManagement(Model model) {
            .
            return something;
        }
    }
```

**I am getting user authorities (List) at the time of login which has 111 in it**

Can any one help me with error am facing?

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've had the similar issue.
In my project there were `@PreAuthorize` annotations 
and also aspects which handled audit logic.
In my case it was enough to:
1. update security config in the following way

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(mode = ASPECTJ, prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`
```

2.add dependency in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope someone will find that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use static modifier for WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

Try following snippet:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
// do your stuff here
```

**@EnableAutoConfiguration**  anotation should be not around your controller but around your application.